# How do I change the theme of this site?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

How can I make this site look like the old SharePoint Overflow?

Comment: Arjun, we are still working through the conversion to the new SE 2.0 setup. Take a look here for more info http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1/sharepoint-overflow-joins-the-stack-exchange-2-0-family. Site theme is one of the things we still need to figure out so if you have suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Until we're out of (or close to out of) beta, we will have this theme. The beta period began when we migrated from the old SharePoint Overflow to Stack Exchange. It will end with our site being launched if we continue to have good metrics - [shown here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint-overflow) - and when we complete various processes such as the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) - tag [started here](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-essential-questions).

Obviously, theme work can be quite time and resource intensive, so we need to prove we are ready to launch before it can be done. (By the way, I have no doubt it will launch, but we have to follow the process.)

In terms of the current theme, it is supposed to look like a "draft" or "sketchpad" that's being worked on - because that's exactly what we're doing! We're building our community and what we want the site to be.

Comment: I think this theme is much better, than the old one, really! :)

Comment: It's so... gray! I definitely don't think the new one is bad, but it could use some color. I did really like the old logo too.

Comment: Guys, this site design is like a wire-frame. It means "graphical design not done yet, just look at the layout".